# Modifying final static variable within final public class Java

Tags: java, reflection, apple-push-notifications, java-9, java-11

I have a quick question regarding modifying a final public class. Based on some researches, it seems like final public class cannot be inherited or implemented. My goal is to change one final static variable within this final public class.

**class name is**: public final class Utils

```
private static final Set<String> DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET = Set.of(
    "authorization", "connection", "cookie", "content-length",
    "date", "expect", "from", "host", "origin", "proxy-authorization",
    "referer", "user-agent", "upgrade", "via", "warning");
```

I want to get rid of `authorization` field from this `DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET`. Is there any ways to doing this?

I heard reflection is one way to modify classes. This is a [Apress/java-9-revealed](https://github.com/Apress/java-9-revealed/blob/master/Java9Revealed/jdk.incubator.httpclient/src/jdk/incubator/http/internal/common/Utils.java) to a github that seems to reveal what's inside of the class

---

This thread (question) has been identified as XY problem. I will try to explain with more information on why I want a solution for the above problem. Before digging into the reason that drove me to ask this question, I will cover the current situation of where this problem is at as of now.

It is important to understand that this problem has been already posed by [Clevertap](https://clevertap.com/) to [Oracle](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194729). If you follow Oracle link, you can see that this problem has been acknowledged and updated to `Jdk 11`. Hopefully, Oracle applies this fixed source code to the coming `Java 10`, but it is highly unlikely given the fact that `Jdk 9` represents `Java 9`. This being said, only solution there is to use reflection which the [open thread in clevertap](https://clevertap.com/blog/java-9-httpclient-does-not-allow-custom-authorization-headers/) suggests.

Now, I will briefly explain what I have achieved and am trying to figure out. I have been working on a framework that I have been developing for sending Push Notification to APNs using Java language. Everything works except one functionality.

[*I will share this framework through GitHub in the near future for those trying to send notification to APNs without depending on third party frameworks, such as Jetty, Netty, or okhttp.*]

The problem rises when I try to use token as a way of authentication to send notification. I have successfully created token following through the instruction provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html). All I have to do is to set request header with `authorization` key and `bearer <token>` value. However, when I use `.setHeader` derived from [jdk9.incubator.httpclient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html) module to set these values, it automatically omits this field. As aforementioned, `authorization` is part of `DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET` and it is clearly not allowed. If a user attempts to set "authorization" as a key value for the request header field, it is deleted. If you have any suggestions to work around this problem. It will be awesome and helpful for others facing the same problem.

---

Bad news folks... `jdk 9.0.4` removed `setSystemHeader` method, so if you want to use `reflection`, you need to use `Jdk 9.0.1`

---

As promised before, I created java library for sending notification using pure java code and pushed it to the [github](https://github.com/CodeBegin/Notice). I used older version that was based on `jdk10` for my published app. Older version only supported tls connection. Now the current version based on `jdk11` is supporting both tls and token based authentication for sending push notification to APNs.

Comment: Can you change the source code and recompile? Why do you want to change this constant, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic Thanks for reading my question. I cannot change the source code because it is part of Java 9. I am trying to get rid of "authorization" field so that I can set header value as "authorization".

Comment: OK. The question would have been much better if you added this information (the "why") along with your research -- which you seem to have done a decent amount -- including the [Java 9 bug](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194729) filed for this problem.

Comment: Can you use `HttpURLConnection#setRequestProperty("authorization", "mytoken")` instead?

Comment: Or then, use the `Authenticator` API instead of modifying the header directly, as shown [here](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/03/14/getting-started-with-java9-httpclient.html).

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic Thanks for your reply and help. As per your suggestion, I need to have http/2 connection, and I am not sure if HttpURLConnection supports that.

Comment: Then, have a look at the `Authenticator` example in the link I posted above.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic I am looking into a way to utilize authenticator as a means to doing this. Thanks for another suggestion :)

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic I think Authenticator only supports for credential setting. For my case, I need to create a request header: setHeader("authorization", "bearer" + <token>) Problem with setHeader in HttpRequest is that "authorization" field is prohibited as described above. I guess reflection is the only way to go. I cannot think of any other good ideas to working around with this problem.

Comment: Good point. Unless you can do this with some other library ([okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)?), then _maybe_ reflection could be considered as the last alternative.

Comment: This really looks like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ... you **should** not even be thinking about such kind of manipulations.

Comment: @MickMnemonic okhttp, jetty, and netty all support this. I just wanted to avoid using third party frameworks since jdk9 supports it. Thank you for your great suggestions though :)

Comment: @GhostCat I see how it could seem like xy problem! Removing authorization from the above code would definitely solve the problem, so I wanted to know if there is any way of doing this. You are indeed correct though. All I am trying to do is set request headers with "authorization" in the safest way possible. Performance comes next.

Comment: Looks like Java's native support for this is lacking in JDK 9, so I'd use a third party instead of reflection. I also think this is an X-Y problem because you were asking for a solution without actually explaining the problem (you asked how to achieve the solution you decided to use). I'm still not sure what your use case is, but it seems like you're trying to pass in APNs request headers with `authorization: bearer <token>`. If you took some time to edit all of this information into the question, I think it can help others that run into this in the future.

Comment: Java 9 not being able to handle this seems like something that could get a patch (before Java 11) if this gets enough attention.

Comment: @MickMnemonic as you have suggested, I just edited the post to contain more information of where this question is coming from.

Comment: @John: Quoting you here: "I will share this framework through GitHub in the near future...", that is my precise goal - no external dependencies. The one that supports JDK 9.0.1 is available here: https://github.com/CleverTap/apns-http2/tree/java9

Answer (score 2):

Will just removing that value from the set work for you? Something like this:

```
        Field f = Utils.class.getDeclaredField("DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set<String> headers = (Set<String>)f.get(null);        
        headers.remove("authorization");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Oh, I do not think I should do this. This class is part of jdk9.incubator source code that limits headers values. I know that they fixed this issue in jdk 11 which is far away from now. I just wanted to see if there is some solution to fixing this problem in the meantime.

Comment: That particular `Set` is immutable, so I doubt that calling `remove` will result in much more than an exception.

Comment: @Lothar Oops, utils is inaccessible. I will try to figure out if I can access this class to test your code :) Thanks for your reply

Comment: Agree. Was not sure if it was using Java9 api.

Comment: @tsolakp I wasn't, either until I tried to call Set.of(...) in my Java8 environment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear for me what are you going achieve by inheritance since this value is static.
But if you possible to recompile your application, have you considered of object composition? This can be an alternate to inheritance and is often used to simulate polymorphic behavior in case of final class or 'multiply' inheritance.
If you can 'inject' the new class instead of original one (which is final), you can compose a new class that contains instance of final class and delegates its methods to them. There is no need to create same final static variable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I do not see how I can utilize object composition to solve this problem. The final class I talk about is part of jdk9 source code. If I were to manipulate this, which many other classes depend on, I do not know how to figure out all these. I just have to removed "authorization" from the above private static final variable or figure out other ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you [wish to bank upon reflection](https://github.com/CleverTap/apns-http2/wiki/Running-on-Java-9), this might help -

```
Class reqClz = request.getClass();

Method setHeaderMethod = reqClz.getDeclaredMethod("setSystemHeader", String.class, String.class);
setHeaderMethod.setAccessible(true);

setHeaderMethod.invoke(request, "authorization", "<token>");
```

for which you might have to open the incubator module's package with the use of VM arg:-

```
--add-opens jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http=<your-package x.y.z>
```

---

**OR**

Was also thinking that, another way here possibly could be [patch the module content](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)

```
--patch-module <module>=<file>(<pathsep><file>)*
```

for the `jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.Utils` class but as recommended not more than testing or debugging purpose.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Clearly, [clevertap.com](https://clevertap.com/blog/java-9-httpclient-does-not-allow-custom-authorization-headers/) was one way to solve this problem. Is there any downside to suing the reflection method?

Comment: @John If the internal implementation of that class changes (declaring a method or a field `private` is a way of saying "we take the right to do whatever we want here), your code will stop working.

Comment: @Lothar 35 Thank you for your answer!!! Could there be any security problems with this? I know that there could be some performance issues according to my research. I just want to make sure that the code I write is going to be safe at all cost.

Comment: @John Reflection is about a thousand times (or more) slower than directly calling the method as long as you don't cache the Method/Field returned by `getDeclaredMethod`/`getDeclaredField`. I can't answer your question about security because that would require me to know what exactly you're doing application-wise and how but I can't come up with general security-issues that might come from that.

Comment: @Lothar Does that mean the above code is going to be very slow? I am just trying to set header value with "authorization" which is blocked by DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET. I wanted to avoid using reflection because  of the reasons you provided. Since [example](https://github.com/Apress/java-9-revealed/blob/916ab1de99eb0b67b94b444fa87a83603fe5b990/Java9Revealed/jdk.incubator.httpclient/src/jdk/incubator/http/HttpRequestImpl.java) shows that the method I am invoking is public no matter what, I guess it is better than gaining direct access to the private method...

Comment: @nullpointer, it would be correct to cite the original source of the code and VM arg setting you copied from clevertap.com.

Answer (score -2):

The following code allows you to change the value of private static fields (non-final):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetFinalField {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("elements before: " + SetTarget.DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET);
        Field f = SetTarget.class.getDeclaredField("DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.addAll((Set<String>) f.get(null));
        l.remove("authorization");
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(l);
        f.set(null, Collections.unmodifiableSet(hs));
        System.out.println("elements after: " + SetTarget.DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET);
    }

    public final static class SetTarget {
        private static Set<String> DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET;

        static {
            HashSet<String> l = new HashSet<>();
            Collections.addAll(l, new String[]{"authorization", "connection", "cookie", "content-length",
                    "date", "expect", "from", "host", "origin", "proxy-authorization",
                    "referer", "user-agent", "upgrade", "via", "warning"});
            DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET = Collections.unmodifiableSet(l);
        }
    }

}
```

If you change the field to `final` this will be prevented, so to answer your question: It's not possible to do what you currently try to do using reflection. There is a way, though by using JNI, but you don't want to go that way. Whatever you try to accomplish you should try to find a different solution, e.g. by checking the class that is using this header if it can be configured with an alternate set of disallowed header values or go the way @nullpointer described.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! If I could, I would change the final class to be non-final class, but the class is part of jdk9.incubator.... I think reflection is the only way to go for now as @nullpointer described.